# Linear search algorithm partially correct

Tags: linear-search

```
def linsearch(list, target):
    for i in range(0, len(list)):
            if (list[i] == target):
                return (i)
            else:
                return ("not in list")

list1 = [1,2,3,4,5]

print(linsearch(list1,1))
```

This is the python program.
Whenever I put target as 1 it returns correct index that is 0, but for all other cases it gives the else case prompt i.e. "not in list"

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? I would assume that your `for` loop should not return `not in list` after having checked the very first item

Comment: You should put the else condition not as an else but as a separate statement outside of the for.

Comment: Please don't remove the code from your question. Share it in text form, not hidden in a screenshot

Comment: Also please don't add images of code, what you had before was better (it just needed code formatting, select the code and press the `{}` button).

Comment: If you place your code inbetween `\`\`\`python` and `\`\`\``, the code will be properly highlighted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You sohuld not return inside the `else` statement. If you have a return in both the `if` and the `else`, you will never proceed to the second iteration of your `for` loop.

You can instead just ommit the `else` completely and just do nothing when `list[i]` does not match your `target`. And only when your code reaches the ent of the `for` loop without returning on a match, return the `"not in list"` value.

```py
def linsearch(list, target):
    for i in range(0, len(list)):
        if (list[i] == target):
            return (i)
    return ("not in list")
```

Comment: Ok, I was making a really silly mistake, thanks a lot for your help.